# Correct usage of asyncio.Condition's wait_for() method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm writing a project using Python's [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio.html) module, and I'd like to synchronize my tasks using its synchronization primitives. However, it doesn't seem to behave as I'd expect.

From the documentation, it seems that [`Condition.wait_for()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Condition.wait_for) offers a means by which to allow a coroutine to wait for a particular user-defined condition to evaluate as true. However, on attempting to use the method, it seems to behave in ways I wouldn't expect - my condition is only checked once, and if it is found to be false, the waiting task simply hangs forever, without ever checking again. I've written a short example below to demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio

thing = False

setter_done = None
getter_done = None

async def main():

    setter_done = asyncio.Event()
    getter_done = asyncio.Event()

    setter = asyncio.ensure_future(set_thing())
    getter = asyncio.ensure_future(get_thing())

    #To avoid the loop exiting prematurely:
    await setter_done.wait()
    await getter_done.wait()

async def set_thing():

    global thing
    global setter_done

    thing = False
    #sleep for some arbitrary amount of time; simulate work happening
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    thing = True

    print("Thing was set to True!")
    setter_done.set()

async def get_thing():

    global thing
    global getter_done

    def check_thing():
        print("Checking...")
        return thing

    c = asyncio.Condition()
    await c.acquire()
    await c.wait_for(check_thing)
    c.release()
    print("Thing was found to be true!")
    getter_done.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I'd expect this to print something like the following:

```sh
Checking...
Thing was set to True!
Checking...
Thing was found to be True!
```

Instead, I get:

```sh
Checking...
Thing was set to True!
... (hangs indefinitely)
```

Comment: You might want to consider using the much simpler `Event` class for signaling between tasks. Unlike threads, asyncio guarantees that no preemption will occur between `await`s, so `Event` can be used safely without the need for additional locking employed by `Condition`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm posting a full answer with a lot of comments to help these with a similar issue.  I've changed the code example to use classes instead of globals.  It's a bit longer but I hope it's not too complicated.

Basically the `Command` class represents a task.  It's asynchronous, so it could do a lot of things.  In my case I create just two dummy commands (read "two tasks"), one pausing for 5 seconds and one for 8 seconds, and I wait for both of them to be over with a condition.  Obviously, conditions aren't the only way to do what I've done, but in keeping with the original answer, I think that's interesting to provide a fully-working example.  So here goes!

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Set

class Command:

    """A command, an asynchronous task, imagine an asynchronous action."""

    async def run(self):
        """To be defined in sub-classes."""
        pass

    async def start(self, condition: asyncio.Condition,
            commands: Set['Command']):
        """
        Start the task, calling run asynchronously.

        This method also keeps track of the running commands.

        """
        commands.add(self)
        await self.run()
        commands.remove(self)

        # At this point, we should ask the condition to update
        # as the number of running commands might have reached 0.
        async with condition:
            condition.notify()

class Look(Command):

    """A subclass of a command, running a dummy task."""

    async def run(self):
        print("Before looking...")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("After looking")

class Scan(Command):

    """A subclass of a command, running a dummy task."""

    async def run(self):
        print("Before scanning...")
        await asyncio.sleep(8)
        print("After scanning")

async def main():
    """Our main coroutine, starting commands."""
    condition = asyncio.Condition()
    commands = set()
    commands.add(Look())
    commands.add(Scan())
    asyncio.gather(*(cmd.start(condition, commands) for cmd in commands))

    # Wait for the number of commands to reach 0
    async with condition:
        await condition.wait_for(lambda: len(commands) == 0)
        print("There's no running command now, exiting.")

asyncio.run(main())
```

So in practice (as usual, start from the end), we call `main` as a coroutine.  In `main` we create two commands, `Look` and `Scan`, and call their `start` method.  The `start` method is defined on every command and it's basically responsible for writing the command itself in a set before it runs, and remove it after it has run (that is, after it's fully finished).  And then it should notify the condition to check the length of commands again.  When there's no command left, the program ends.  If you run this script (I ran it with Python 3.8) you should see something like:

```
Before scanning...
Before looking...
After looking
After scanning
There's no running command now, exiting.
```

Notice that both commands start at the same time (well, `Look` begins slightly before, as a matter of fact, but still, `Scan` begins before `Look` is done).  But `Look` does end before `Scan` does (roughly 3 seconds).  Our condition isn't checked until both commands are done.

Could events or locks or semaphores be used instead?  Possibly, but I like to use a condition in that example.  You can easily have a lot more tasks without a lot of modifications.

Comment: Using a condition looks unintuitively at first. Usually you would expect it to deadlock when having two (or more) `async with condition` blocks, but `Condition.wait()`/`Condition.wait_for()` release the lock again after it has been acquired (before leaving the `async with` block).

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `c.notify_all()` after you set thing to true. Conditions only check their predicate after they are "notified", otherwise nothing happens.