# How to pass an event into an async task from another thread?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

In python asyncio it is straightforward if everything runs under the same event loop in one thread.

How can you pass an event from another thread that runs in normal multi-threading mode?

The closest [I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708124/correct-usage-of-asyncio-conditions-wait-for-method) is:

- In the async domain:

  ```
  thing = False # global
  c = asyncio.Condition() # global

  def check_thing():
      print("Checking...", thing)
      return thing

  async def hello_task():
      print("acquire")
      await c.acquire()
      await c.wait_for(check_thing)
      c.release()
      print("releqse")
      #...

  def hello_notify(): # called from another thread
      global thing
      thing = True
      print("notify")
      c.notify_all()
  ```
- In another thread:

  ```
  hello_notify()
  ```

When `hello_notify()` is called from another normal thread, it throws an `RuntimeError('cannot notify on un-acquired lock')` exception.

How can this be solved without changing everything into asyncio model? I do see "acquire" printed before "notify", but "release" not printed, so the condition is "locked" I assume? Since the condition is acquired, does it mean "un-acquired" in the calling thread?

In general, how can you pass an event from another thread into an async task in python?

Comment: it sounds like you are looking for [`loop.call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading)

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in a comment, you need to use `call_soon_threadsafe`. For example:

```
thing = asyncio.Event()
_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def hello_task():
    print("waiting for thing")
    await thing.wait()
    thing.clear()
    #...

def hello_notify(): # called from another thread
    print("notify")
    # tell the event loop to call thing.set()
    _loop.call_soon_threadsafe(thing.set)
```

Note that asyncio doesn't require a mutex to protect the shared resource because asyncio objects can only be modified from the thread that runs the asyncio event loop. Because of that a full-blown `asyncio.Condition` is in fact rarely needed.

Answer (score 2):

I created the following code and I pass `threading.Event` to Thread with asyncio task to stop it's work, is it what you want to achieve?

```py
import asyncio
import time
import threading


async def do_work(e: threading.Event):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        if e.is_set():
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print(counter)
        counter += 1
    print("Async do_work was stopped")


def another_tread(e):
    asyncio.run(do_work(e))
    print("Another thread finished it's work")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    e = threading.Event()
    another_th = threading.Thread(target=another_tread, args=(e, ), daemon=False)
    another_th.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Send stop Event")
    e.set()
    time.sleep(10)
    print("Main trhead finished")
```

Another way to solve the issue if we do not want to use `threading.Event` due to it's blocking nature:

```py
import asyncio
import time
import threading


async def print_hello(_e: asyncio.Event):
    """Some function to prove that asyncio loop really run in another thread
    while we're waitng for event in main thread"""
    while True:
        print("Hello")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        if _e.is_set():
            break


async def alert(_e: asyncio.Event):
    """Waiting for event from another thread"""
    await event.wait()
    print("ALERT")


async def main_work(_e: asyncio.Event):
    """Wrapper to combine print_hello and alert"""
    # task are created to run coroutine simultaneously
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(print_hello(_e))
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(alert(_e))
    await t1
    await t2


async def stop_loop(_e: asyncio.Event):
    """The coroutine which raise event for main_work"""
    _e.set()
    print("Stop loop")


def main_async(_loop: asyncio.ProactorEventLoop, _e: asyncio.Event):
    """Another thread to run loop"""
    try:
        _loop.run_until_complete(main_work(_e))
    finally:
        print("Loop is closed")
        _loop.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # create loop
    event = asyncio.Event()  # create event
    # send loop and to another thread
    th = threading.Thread(target=main_async, args=(loop, event), name="ThreadAsync")
    th.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    # alert loop, which run in another thread
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(stop_loop(event), loop)
    time.sleep(5)
    th.join()
    print("MAIN THREAD IS FINISHED")
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the solution. Though, if you can change `if e.is_set()` into `await e`, and remove the `await asyncio.sleep(2)`, it would be a perfect valid solution for me. I don't like the `await asyncio.sleep(2)` because I know how to achieve the same without the event. I'm looking a way to pass an event without incur extra delay.

Comment: @minghua unfortunately you can not wait for ```threading.Event``` in ```asyncio``` loop since it will block the whole loop. I developed another solution if you do not want to use polling of  ```threading.Event``` state in one of coroutines. Please check and share your opinion

Comment: Great! Thanks. It looks more like what I wanted. So if the two tasks run in infinite loops, you'll need to clear the event in alert task?

Comment: @minghua Yes to to stop infinite loop in one task you have to "raise" event in another task. On the other hand ```await event.wait()``` block all code after it in the coroutine, if you do not need doing any work in the coroutine while waiting for event, you can use it though.