# How to deal with two event loops? Pyrogram's and Tkinter's

Tags: python, tkinter, telegram, python-multithreading, pyrogram

I am using Pyrogram and Tkinter:

```
from tkinter import *
from pyrogram import Client

root = Tk()
app = Client("my_account")
```

First, I register a handler with Pyrogram:

```
@app.on_message()
def message(client, message):
    print("Message!")
```

Second, I register a handler with Tkinter:

```
def button(event):
    print("Button!")
    
root.bind('<Button>', button)
```

But how can I start the loops for Pyrogram and Tkinter?
Obviously the following (or the reverse) does not work:

```
root.mainloop()
app.run()
```

**Edit:** Since one of the key feature of Pyrogram is that it is fully asynchronous (e.g., https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/updates#registering-a-handler), I would expect an answer based on Asyncio. Here is however my attempt with threading following comments by @SylvesterKruin.

```
t = Thread(target=app.run)
t.start()
root.mainloop()
```

Il fails with `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'`.

Comment: I don't know Pyrogram, but would using threading work? You could have the `tkinter` code in the main thread and the `pyrogram` code in another thread.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin This might be an answer. But one of the key feature of `pyrogram` is that it is fully asynchronous (e.g., https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/updates#registering-a-handler), so I would expect an answer based on `asyncio`.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I have edited my question with an attempt at threading.

Comment: Why are you creating a second thread for `tkinter`, and a third thread for `pyrogram`? You need to run `tkinter` in the _main_ thread. That is, you don't need to create a separate thread for `tkinter`; just run all the `tkinter` stuff as you normally would without using threading.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I have edited accordingly. But it still fails.

Comment: Hmm... well, then maybe `asyncio` is the best bet, especially since you're looking for an `asyncio` answer anyway. I'm sorry, but I hardly know anything about asynchronous programming, so I won't be able to help you out there. Best of luck!

Comment: As @SylvesterKruin stated in the first place, you should use a thread to sperate `pyrogram` and `tkinter` it makes things cleaner, even if there are [work arounds for asyncio and tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47896365/13629335), you will need to synchronize the api- and gui-framework anyway. [Exampels for tkinter and threading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16745507/13629335) are available and as soon as you have something to show, that actually works, I suggest to post your code at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where you can get additional input.

Comment: Even if I upvoted your question, since it seems usefull and has research in it. It currently states multiple question at once and isnt suitable for [so]. So I am voting to close this question, but feel free to ask a follow up question that has more focus at a particular error or unexpacted behavior. You may ask this question at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or another [sites by Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#)

Comment: @Bob Didn't the answer I gave below work?

Answer (score -2):

A bit of looking through the [pyrogram examples](https://docs.pyrogram.org/start/examples/) and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64652168/7907587) to prevent blocking. I think this might be helpful.

```
import asyncio
import tkinter as tk
from pyrogram import Client
import threading

api_id = 12345
api_hash = "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"
app = Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash)

def init_async():
    print('starting')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # create loop
    event = asyncio.Event()  # create event
    #new thread to run loop. Prevents tkinter from blocking
    thr = threading.Thread(target=run_main, args=(loop, event))
    thr.start()

def run_main(_loop, _e):
    try:
        _loop.run_until_complete(main())
    finally:
        _loop.close()


async def main():
    async with app:
        await app.send_message("me", "Greetings from **Pyrogram**!")

@app.on_message()
async def message(client, message):
    print("Message!")

def button(event):
    print("Button!")

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind('<Button>', button)
tk.Button(master=root, text='Start Pyrogram', command=init_async).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What about the handler `button` that I would to like to register with Tkinter?

Comment: Handler `button` included

Comment: It does not work. When I receive a message, the handler `message` is not called.

Comment: Your original challenge was "how can I start the loops for Pyrogram and Tkinter", this does that. You might want to ask a new question for this.